# irregular polyline google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline

I have implemented polyline for google map for joining the markers on the google map. Polyline is getting displayed but it is trying to join all the points (some isolated points also) which is creating irregular shapes. Please see the snapshots:

[image]
[image]

I need to reomve that irregular shapes. Is there any way I can do that?? If not than should i go to use some other functionality of google map for implementating the same. I am using mysql database from which the lat long is imported and is displayed on map with xml output. Every help will be appreciated. If you are not clear with my doubts, feel free to ask for detailed explanation. I will be glad to clarify each and every point.

My code is as below

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.00000, 80.00000),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
 var flightPlanCoordinates = new google.maps.MVCArray(); 
 var bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("navigatormapxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var gpsdata = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < gpsdata.length; i++) {
      var id = gpsdata[i].getAttribute("id");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(gpsdata[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(gpsdata[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      flightPlanCoordinates.insertAt(flightPlanCoordinates.length, point);
      var speed = gpsdata[i].getAttribute("speed");
      var altitude = gpsdata[i].getAttribute("altitude");
      var html = "<b>Accuracy = +/- </b>" + id + "<br/><b> Speed = </b>" + speed + " Kmph";
      var icon = customIcons[id] || {};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });

     bounds.extend(point);
     map.fitBounds(bounds);       
     map.panToBounds(bounds);
     bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 5
  });
flightPath.setMap(map); 

  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The polyline is created using the array that you have passed in your case "flightPlanCoordinates" array. It will join the first point of the array to the second point, the second point to the third point and so on. If your array itself contains those points then they will be plotting in the polyline. One solution would be to remove the irregular points from the database. Another thing that you need to check is whether the retrieved points are in the correct order. That should eliminate the irregular shapes.